# How to delay the else statement without coroutine in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I have a joystick display picture for my game. Currently, when the player touches the screen the image disappears and when the player is not touching the screen, it reappears. I wrote that using an if else statement.

```cs
if (indicator.inputIndicator.x != 0)
{
    joystick.SetActive(false);
}
else
{
    joystick.SetActive(true);
}
```

The problem is, I want the image to reappear after some time like 2 seconds. I want to delay the "else", but I do not want to use a coroutine. I want "else" to work after 2 seconds since the player takes his hand off the screen but I couldn't figure out how to do it. any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a timer is a pretty common problem you have to solve in Unity. One basic approach is to have a variable that you add [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) every update. That way you can tell how long it has been since some condition was met.

Every Update iteration that meets the condition, add `Time.deltaTime` to the variable. If at some point the condition fails, reset the variable to 0. Then you can just base your `joystick.SetActive()` call on the value of your variable.

For example, your script might become:

```cs
float thresholdTimeToShowPrompt = 2;

// By starting at the threshold, the image is hidden at the start until a touch
float timeSincePlayerTouch = 2;

void Update()
{
    // Rather than calling SetActive directly, just update the timer
    if (indicator.inputIndicator.x != 0)
    {
        timeSincePlayerTouch = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        timeSincePlayerTouch += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    // Now we can base visibility on the time since the last user touch
    bool shouldShowIcon = timeSincePlayerTouch >= thresholdTimeToShowPrompt;
    
    // Only call SetActive when needed, in case of overhead
    if (shouldShowIcon && !joystick.activeSelf)
    {
        joystick.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (!shouldShowIcon && joystick.activeSelf)
    {
        joystick.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's great and thank you for your help. It works well but the problem with that is when the game starts image also comes after the delay.

Comment: @icarus I see what you mean - to start with the image already hidden, you can initialize the timer variable at the threshold time. I've updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: oh, that makes sense, i was preoccupied with something else. it's working just like i want it to be. thank you for all your help, i am grateful.